# An unknown file names runner

Tags: python, visual-studio, installation, interpreter, vscode-code-runner

I have a problem using visual studio. When I was trying to install an interpreter (code runner) I don't know what I did after I typed "code runner" (probably just pressed enter) and a file opened, named runner and it doesn't let me to go to other files. It just become active after one second I switch to another python file or tab. I cannot delete the file, it's like a virus!
I uninstalled VS code and installed it again and in between deleted the file. But it is still there and shows up in the installed VS code again! What should I do to get rid of it?